# Why is typename required in such a case?

Tags: c++, templates, types, standards, typename

```
#include <string>

template<typename>
void g()
{}

template<typename T>
void f()
{
    g<typename T::value_type>(); // ok
    g<T::value_type>(); // ok
    typename T::value_type n1; // ok
    T::value_type n2; // failure        
}

int main()
{
    f<std::string>();
}
```

Compiled with vc++.

In the code above, whether `T::value_type` is a type or a variable can be determined at compile-time. There is no ambiguity here, or `g<T::value_type>()` will also be required written as `g<typename T::value_type>()`.

**Why is typename required in such a case?**

**What's the rationale behind?**

Comment: Is this a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245 ?

Comment: Your second "okay" needs reviewing http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05ba64ce504ff3fc

Comment: Visual C++ you say? Microsoft is really bad in following the standard for templates. Try using `/permissive-` once available (VS2017) to get slightly better standard compliance